# Can you define a context manager in a class, that skill can be used by it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently working in python with selenium, and i have the following problem.

I want to use Selenium / BeautifulSoup to fetch stuff from a specific website. I need to send requests via selenium to a couple of pages.
For this, i have written a class that takes the Url and then does the things i want to do. I wrote it inside a single file so I can import it into another one that actually gives it the urls (theres a reason for this, but explaining my reasoning for this would not lead anywhere).

Since selenium's startup is slow and i need to add cookies (which would be a waste of time if i had to do it for every single request), i want to create the selenium driver once and then use it for the whole program run. Since I may want to import this stuff into different projects, i would like to create the selenium driver inside the class and use it from there.

And to make sure I dont accidentaly leave the driver open when the program crashes or whatever, i wanna use a context manager (`with webdriver as d:`). The problem is, i dont know how i can actually use this. If i put this code in a function inside the class, the context manager closes once the function is over. Its not like a requests session, where i can just return the request.Session() object and use it wherever i want, right?

I hope this is understandable and i also hope that some of you may have an idea of what I could do here. Best regards!

Comment: Nothing is left open when the program ends normally or crashes.  All files and connections are closed.  If the resource needs to be open for the lifetime of the object that contains it, then there is no reason to use a context manager.  The reference will go out of scope when the container does.

Comment: Are you sure you need Selenium, rather than using something like `requests`?

Comment: Right.  Remember that a Selenium instance only maintains one URL at a time.  You can't use a single instance to be scraping several sites at once.

Comment: "theres a reason for this, but explaining my reasoning for this would not lead anywhere" -- no explanation is needed, that's the normal way that classes and modules are used. They implement a general mechanism, and you provide the variable data when you call the functions.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ah okay, thanks! I tried googling my problem and found a site claiming i should always quit selenium because it would stay open otherwise. Thought it was because the browsers was controlled via the webdriver.exe, which could stay open without python.

Comment: @chepner yeah i need selenium because some of the things i want to scrape are only loaded once you scrolled past them, which i cant easily do with requests, but it easy with selenium